# Does chrome still use NSS libraries

Tags: disassembly

Is NSS Libraries still present on recent version of chrome. When I reverse Chrome using API monitor, I tend to see Netscape security service (NSS) Libraries present.

Comment: Are you looking for the TLS library or just wondering about the purpose of NSS in Chrome (if it is used at all)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a UNIX system, you can easily check if an executable program is using (or not) a dynamic library with the `ldd` program. For example, if you want to look for this on `chromium`:

```
#> which chromium
/usr/bin/chromium
#> file /usr/bin/chromium
/usr/bin/chromium: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Looking for the real executable (looking inside the script that run Chrome), I finally got the real path to the executable which was `/usr/lib/chromium/chromium`:

```
#> file /usr/lib/chromium/chromium 
/usr/lib/chromium/chromium: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, 
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,
for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0880d1837b9c423a478251743408a62ca4433677,
not stripped
```

Then, I simply use `ldd` on it:

```
#> ldd /usr/lib/chromium/chromium | grep nss
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x7f742651d000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x7f74262ed000)
```

Here we go!